# Copy files to the same folder, but with new name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The question seems to be pretty simple, but I haven't found solution myself.

I need to copy files to the same folder, but with different name.

Here is what works for me, but obviously, it doesn't do the trick:

```
for /f %%f in ("*.exe") do copy "%%f" "%%f_a"
```

Of course, in this example "New Folder" should be created manually.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
C:\Test\foo.exe -> C:\Test\foo_a.exe
C:\Test\bar.exe -> C:\Test\bar_a.exe
C:\Test\baz.exe -> C:\Test\baz_a.exe
```

I tried to play with parameter extensions, [as shown here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), but with no luck, currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy enough in PowerShell. Use the System.IO.FileInfo members to construct the desired name. When you are confident that the new names are correct, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.exe' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName `
            -Destination $($_.DirectoryName+'\'+$_.BaseName+'_a'+$_.Extension) -WhatIf
    }
```

If you must run this in a cmd.exe shell, put the PowerShell code in a file such as renexe.ps1 and run it with this command.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File renexe.ps1
```

If you do not want to or are not permitted to push ahead into PowerShell, it can be done with cmd.exe. When you are satisfied that the `COPY` command is correct, remove the `echo` from it.

```
FOR /F %%f IN ('DIR /B /A:-D "*.exe"') DO (
    echo COPY "%%~f" "%%~nf_a%%~xf"
)
```

Comment: I oftenly see someting like `DIR /B /A-D` (without colon after `A`) on Stack Overflow. Is there any difference between using `DIR /B /A:-D` and `DIR /B /A-D` (without colon)? Both works, but probably they are not the same?

Comment: @jsv - To my knowledge `/A:-D` and `/A-D` are equivalent. The colon is optional, but it is part of the documentation from `DIR /?`.